# Test-Drive Android

Tags: android, testing

Does somebody has some experience with test-driving android? After some research on the internet I have found some frameworks but don't know which I should take. Here is list of the frameworks that I've already found:

- Android Testing Framework
- Robotium
- Robolectric
- MonkeyRunner

Which one do you recommend?

Comment: It depends what you are doing. I use JMockIt where I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Robotium. Its really powerful for testing UI components. But needs a bit Java understanding. Nevertheless you can collaborate with other android automation tests developers through [google.groups/robotium-developers](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/robotium-developers), this is a large community where easy to find help. Practically every months new updates. And you can combine it with Android Testing Framework and WebDriver. 
More and more new people become involved in development of this open source project.